One master switch controlling 3 sub switches possible?
Is it possible for one master switch, say at entrance of bedroom, control in some way, 3 different light switches that each controll a recessed light?  Not looking to add relays, just using existing wiring and smart switches at the bed (e.g. treatlife dimmer switches).  See attached image.  Each color is the associated switch and light.  There is already a switch at the main entrance, which is like to control all.  Meaning of that is off, all switches are off, even if the local switch is on. 

4 way switch ..

To clarify what I think you are asking: 4 switches - 1 main, 3 for individual fixtures; when main is on, individual fixtures controlled by individual switches; when main is off; all off; when main turned back on, status of 3 switches resumes as previously - e.g., Main on, A on, B off, C on = lights A and C on; turn off Main - all off; turn on Main - A and C on again. Correct?

What wiring do you have available? Also, are you locked into a platform for smartswitches already, or are your choices open in that regard?

@manassehkatz - correct.

One restriction here: one of the switches near the door will need to always switch a light on in order to meet code.

Are you in the US/Canada or someplace else? Wiring practices vary so specifics will depend on where you are located.

How about smart switches?  I think you should be able to program so that each light's switch will operate it, yet one switch can override all lights.

If I understand correctly, you want an override shut-off switch, such that if the override switch is "off", all the lights are off, but if the override switch is "on", the lights are controlled by their respective switches. In that case, assuming you're willing and able to do a little rewiring, you don't need smart switches at all. Instead, you can simply wire the override switch upstream of all three other switches, like so:

       │
       │ Wiring coming into room
       │
       \ Override switch (at entrance)
       │
┌──────┼──────┐
│      │      │
\S1    \S2    \S3
│      │      │
@      @      @

(Where '\' represents a switch and '@' a light. Neutral and ground wiring omitted for simplicity.)
If redoing the wiring is not an option, you can instead replace all four switches with your choice of smart switches (it will work best if they are all the same make and model). Depending on the brand of your switches, there may be an option in the provided software to have the "downstream" switches only work when the override switch is on. If not, there are probably third-party hook-ins that will let you achieve the effect. Personally, my smart switch is controlled from Automagic Premium using IFTTT as a bridge to the manufacturer's control app. Those are not recommendations, because my solution sucks (it relies on three phone apps, one of which is no longer maintained).
Better-chosen switches (ideally controlled over a standard protocol such as Z-Wave) will hopefully let you come up with a more elegant solution.

Nice answer! One thing that could be added, per KMJ's comment above: Some jurisdictions require the switch at the door to turn on one light for the room always. So OP may be required to keep one room light out of the sub-switch scheme and control it only from the main door switch.
